# The distance for generating a stronghold

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

- Where does strongholds generate?
- What is the approximate distance for strongholds to generate (from spawnpoint to stronghold chunk)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Info from [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold):

### Java Edition

All strongholds are located at random coordinates within rings in most Strongholds biomes, where each ring is a certain radius from the center of the world (`x = 0, z = 0`). The strongholds are generated at roughly equal angles from the center point of the world (for instance, each stronghold in a ring of 3 is in the region of 120 degrees from the others, measured from the origin). There are eight rings, containing 128 strongholds in total.

> - The first ring has 3 strongholds within 1,280-2,816 blocks of the origin.
> - The second ring has 6 strongholds within 4,252-5,888 blocks of the origin.
> - The third ring has 10 strongholds within 7,424-8,960 blocks of the origin.
> - The fourth ring has 15 strongholds within 10,496-12,032 blocks of the origin.
> - The fifth ring has 21 strongholds within 13,568-15,104 blocks of the origin.
> - The sixth ring has 28 strongholds within 16,640-18,176 blocks of the origin.
> - The seventh ring has 36 strongholds within 19,712-21,248 blocks of the origin.
> - The eighth and outermost ring has 9 strongholds within 22,784-24,320 blocks of the origin.

### Bedrock Edition

Strongholds generate randomly throughout the world. They have a higher chance to generate under a village. They appear to have no fixed set distance, unlike most structures, which means that rarely, they can overlap.